# Why does this Java program work counter to my expectations?

Tags: java

Why does this program work counter to my expectations?

I expect: 1 50 47 50
I get: 0 50 0 50

```
class Poppet {
    int i;
    Poppet(int i) {
        i = i;
    }
}

class Ideone
{
    private final int i = 50; // Initialized final
    private final int j; // Blank final
    private final Poppet p; // Blank final reference
    // Blank finals MUST be initialized in the constructor:
    public Ideone() {
        j = 1; // Initialize blank final
        p = new Poppet(1); // Initialize blank final reference
        System.out.println(p.i);
    }
    public Ideone(int x) {
        j = x; // Initialize blank final
        p = new Poppet(x); // Initialize blank final reference
        System.out.println(p.i);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Ideone t = new Ideone();
        System.out.println(t.i);
        Ideone r = new Ideone(47);
        System.out.println(r.i);
    }
}
```

Can you please explain why?

Comment: Don't just post link to your code. post your code here instead.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I've tried, but the stackoverflow's word - processor writes an error, reporting that there is too much code. How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local variable shadowing, as described in [JLS 6.4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1).

If you want to set the instance variable `i`, you have to prefix it as in `this.i`.

```
class Poppet {
    int i;
    Poppet(int i) {
       this.i = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3380686, You are very welcome, and you are certainly not the first to make this mistake. :)

Answer (score 4):

Change:

```
Poppet(int i) {
   i = i;
}
```

to:

```
Poppet(int i) {
    this.i = i;
}
```

by doing `i = i` you're assigning the method argument to itself while what you really want to do is to assign it to the class member variable.

Comment: If the `int i` in `Poppet` were a blank final too, the compiler would've caught this mistake.  :-)